# Updating .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component file in a maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven

I working with a maven project in eclipse and am having trouble with getting the deployment to work without some manual editing of xml files.

When I build the project through maven I get a org.eclipse.wst.common.component xml file in my .settings folder. The file looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="ins-web">           
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/java"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="ins-web"/>
        <property name="java-output-path"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

The following line is causing the problem:

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent"/>
```

Its looking to deploy everything below the WebContent folder when really it should be looking in src/webapp. The line should therefore look like this:

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/webapp"/>
```

If I change it manually then it all works fine but I'd like to know if there is a way to avoid manually changing the file to make the build process easier for other people on my team.

Comment: How did you do eclipse project? Manually or by maven-eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 4):

How are you generating your eclipse files. Are you using the [m2eclipse Eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) or are your using the [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/)? m2eclipse is a plugin for Eclipse, run inside Eclipse. the maven-eclipse-plugin is a Maven plugin run from the cmd line to generate Eclipse project files based on your pom.xml.

I have always had better success using the maven-eclipse-plugin. The authors of m2eclipse do not suggest you try to use both plugins together.

If you are using the maven-eclipse-plugin, you should check a couple of things.

1. Use the latest maven-eclipse-plugin version 2.7.
2. Make sure your project is a 'war' packaging'
3. Configure the maven-war-plugin as well and set the war source directory as you see fit. Add the following snippet to your pom.xml. This is how the maven-eclipse-plugin determines where your webapp lives.

```
  <plugin>  
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>2.1-beta-1</version>  
    <configuration>  
      <warSourceDirectory>src/webapp</warSourceDirectory>  
    </configuration>  
  </plugin>
```

After making these changes and running `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` again, you should see the expected value in your component file.

Comment: Hi Peter,

i am not using the maven-eclipse-plugin. I run all maven commands from the command line.

I did a search across my project for a place to set "warSourceDirectory" but could not find one...

Comment: It sounds like you think the maven-eclipse-plugin is an Eclipse plugin run inside eclipse. It is not. It is a Maven plugin executed from the cmd line. warSourceDirectory is part of the maven-war-plugin configuration found inside your Maven pom.xml for your project.

Answer (score 2):

In maven-eclipse-plugin config add...

```
<additionalConfig>
  <file>
    <name>.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component</name>
    <content>
      <![CDATA[Your file content here
      ]]>
    </content>
  </file>
</additionalConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to regenerate the file for JAR (only), on the project, right click > Properties > Project Facets:
 - Check the Java option and choose the Java version. It will generate the file **org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core** into the *.settings* folder
 - Check the Utility Module. It will generate the file **org.eclipse.wst.common.component** into the *.settings* folder
 - Click on Apply button and/or OK button

This is only a way to generate the file for your IDE environment. From our understanding, one reason of why m2e-wtp does not generate correctly the file is a "bad" POM. It seems that the Project Facets are deduced from the pom.xml file and their relationships between other projects/modules (ex.: Dependencies with a web module/Java EE project type).